# How to catch table in pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have to extract some pdf files. I want to catch some tables in these pdf files. I have some tables in a pdf file which are surrounded with txt. How can I catch these tables by pdfbox?

Comment: **A)** What have you tried? **B)** PDF (unless tagged) does not know the concept of tables; what you perceive as a table merely is a hodgepodge of text chunk plus possibly some lines or colored background rectangles. Thus, table recognition and extraction is not trivial and, therefore, usually not part of the base PDF library (PDFBox, iText, ...) but instead a project in its own right based on such a base library, e.g. [tabula](https://tabula.technology/).

Comment: I have tried to find table by regular expression and handle Strings but I can't find where the table is over.And I find this question from Google,but some answer is about only table pdf file which is unhelpful.Can you give me some advice?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I can use Image recognition to deal with this question?I will have a try.:)

Comment: If the tables you have to extract are similar to each other (e.g. all with border lines or all with background coloration, etc.), you might provide an example PDF to make it easier helping you. If your tables are not similar to each other, this topic is too broad for a stackoverflow Q&A and you'd most likely need a project like tabula anyways.

Comment: Sorry,maybe I didn't said clearly.My project need to analysis some paper,but some table in paper causes some problem. So I need to catch these tables or just delete them.Thanks for your advices,I will learn tabula to solve my problem.

Comment: @mkl,I find there are plenty of examples of how to call it from the command line or use it in Python but there doesn't seem to be any documentation for use in Java.Where will I find some examples of java?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java - "tabula-java is a library for extracting tables from PDF files — it is the table extraction engine that powers Tabula (repo). You can use tabula-java as a command-line tool to programmatically extract tables from PDFs." - There should be samples there somewhere.